# Getting SSL error when sending email via Django

Tags: python, django, smtp, gmail

This is what I see when I send mail via Django:

> [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:997)

This is my email configuration in settings.py:

```py
# Email Settings
EMAIL_BACKEND = "django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend"
EMAIL_HOST = "smtp.gmail.com"
EMAIL_PORT = 587
EMAIL_HOST_USER = "xxxxxxxx@gmail.com"
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = "xxxxxxxxxxxxx"
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
```

And this is how I send mail:

```py
send_mail(
    "Subject",
    "Test message",
    settings.EMAIL_HOST_USER,
    ["xxxxxxxxx@gmail.com"],
    fail_silently=False,
)
```

Comment: What Django and Python versions are you using? We can't really help you unless you give us some version information.

Comment: Django 4 and python 3.10

Answer (score 4):

The default configuration has changed in Django 4.2, see [here](https://medium.com/@hhuysamen/sending-emails-using-django-4-2-3e5de1ff64dc) for details and workaround.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34616138)

Answer (score 2):

I was using Django 4.2 and Python 3.10, running into the same issue. Downgrading Django to 4.1.7 worked for me. Hope this helps

Answer (score 2):

*The top voted answer helps me solve the issue. Just add this answer with more details.*

*Thanks to [this post](https://medium.com/@hhuysamen/sending-emails-using-django-4-2-3e5de1ff64dc).*

#### Reason

> This is due to the ssl_context.check_hostname field in the django.core.mail.backends.smtp.py file being set to True by default, starting from Django 4.2.

#### Solution

##### In test environment:

In the `settings.py`:

```
EMAIL_USE_TLS = False
```

**Note**: This should only be used for development. It is important that TLS is enabled for production or any public facing service.

##### In production environment:

1. Create a custom email backend to set the `check_hostname` and `verify_mode` values.

```py
# file path: backend/email.py
import ssl

from django.core.mail.backends.smtp import EmailBackend as SMTPBackend
from django.utils.functional import cached_property


class EmailBackend(SMTPBackend):
  @cached_property
  def ssl_context(self):
      if self.ssl_certfile or self.ssl_keyfile:
          ssl_context = ssl.SSLContext(protocol=ssl.PROTOCOL_TLS_CLIENT)
          ssl_context.load_cert_chain(self.ssl_certfile, self.ssl_keyfile)
          return ssl_context
      else:
          ssl_context = ssl.create_default_context()
          ssl_context.check_hostname = False
          ssl_context.verify_mode = ssl.CERT_NONE
          return ssl_context
```

2. Use the custom backend rather than the standard one

```py
# settings.py
# EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend' # old value
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'backend.email.EmailBackend'
```

Answer (score -2):

If you are encountering compatibility issues or errors when using Django 4.2 with Python 3.10, you may consider downgrading Django to a compatible version. Here are more detailed steps to downgrade Django:

1. Identify the compatible Django version: Determine the Django version that is compatible with Python 3.10. You can refer to the Django project's documentation, release notes, or compatibility matrix to find the recommended Django version for Python 3.10.
2. Update the Django version in requirements.txt: Open the `requirements.txt` file in your Django project's root directory. Locate the line that specifies the Django version, which may look like `Django==4.2`. Replace the version number with the compatible Django version. For example, if Django 4.1.7 is compatible, the line should be changed to `Django==4.1.7`.
3. Save the changes: Save the updated `requirements.txt` file.
4. Install the compatible Django version: Open a terminal or command prompt and navigate to your Django project's directory. Run the following command to install the compatible Django version:

   ```
   pip install -r requirements.txt --upgrade
   ```

   This command will install the specified Django version and its dependencies.
5. Verify the Django version: After the installation completes, you can verify that Django has been downgraded to the compatible version by running the following command:

   python -m django --version

   This command will display the currently installed Django version, which should match the downgraded version you specified in `requirements.txt`.

By following these steps, you can successfully downgrade Django to a compatible version and resolve any compatibility issues with Python 3.10. It's important to note that downgrading Django may impact certain features or functionalities available in newer versions, so be sure to test your application thoroughly after the downgrade.

Installing collected packages: Django
Attempting uninstall: Django
Found existing installation: Django 4.2.2
Uninstalling Django-4.2.2:
Successfully uninstalled Django-4.2.2
Successfully installed Django-4.1.7

python3 -m django --version

4.1.7

pip install -r requirements.txt --upgrade

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, 
Vivek kumar jha!

Your answer appears likely to have been written (entirely or partially) by AI (e.g., ChatGPT). A heads-up that [posting AI-generated content is not allowed here](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/421831). If you used an AI tool to assist with any answer, I would encourage you to delete it.

We do hope you'll be a part of our community and contribute with *your own*, quality posts in the future. Thanks!

Comment: **Readers should review this answer carefully and critically, as AI-generated information often contains fundamental errors and misinformation.** If you observe quality issues and/or have reason to believe that this answer was generated by AI, please leave feedback accordingly.